# Tag based search relating another Table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

Blog table

```
id      blog        description
1    Simple PHP   Nothing But simple
2    Simple JS    Nothing But JS
```

Second Table is Tags

```
id   tag
 1    JS
 2    PHP
 3    mysql
```

Third Table is Blog_Tag

```
   id   blog_id  tag_id
    1      1       2
    2      1       3
    3      2       1
```

So what I need is a search based `tag` 
here is what I tried

For example If I search with PHP and Mysql Tags Blog with id 1 should come

```
 Select Blog.* From Blog B INNER JOIN Blog_Tag BT ON(B.id=BT.blog_id) 
 WHERE BT.tag_id = 2 OR BT.tag_id=3
```

But this query outputs Blog 1 multiple times.any solutions?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: thanks @Barmar Forgot that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this in both `tag_id 2 and 3` Same `Blog.ID` comes. Look at this query

```
Select B.*,BT.tag_id From Blog B INNER JOIN Blog_Tag BT ON(B.id=BT.blog_id) 
 WHERE BT.tag_id = 2 OR BT.tag_id=3
```

For the Solution for unique data you need to use `Distinct` like i use in below query

`Select DISTINCT B.* From Blog B INNER JOIN Blog_Tag BT ON(B.id=BT.blog_id) 
 WHERE BT.tag_id = 2 OR BT.tag_id=3`

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct or group by in your query like

`distinct blog` or `group by blog`.

```
Select DISTINCT blog, B.* From Blog B INNER JOIN Blog_Tag BT ON(B.id=BT.blog_id) 
 WHERE BT.tag_id = 2 OR BT.tag_id=3

Select * From Blog B INNER JOIN Blog_Tag BT ON(B.id=BT.blog_id) 
 WHERE BT.tag_id = 2 OR BT.tag_id=3 GROUP BY blog
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple where gives all answers to the query. and in your case blog 1 fits the bill twice. if you want singular answers i suggest in looking to the group by command.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to above mentioned problem  please try executing following SQL query

```
select * from blog where id in(select blog_id from blog_tag where tag_id in(2,3))
```